# For loop to Iterate through an array and create divs that are siblings of each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get my `game2` element to have two child divs containing the contents of the `gameTwo` array, but what is happening in this script is that the first time it iterates through the loop, it creates the child div I want, but the second time it creates a child of the child. Can someone advise on how I can edit this so that the divs are both siblings of each other?

`var gameTwo = ['Kansas', 'Villanova']`

```
var gameTwoText = '';
    for (i = 0; i < gameTwo.length; i++) {
        gameTwoText += "<div>" + gameTwo[i];
    }
var secondGame = document.getElementById('game2').innerHTML = gameTwoText;
```

Comment: You're not closing the <div> tag in your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closing tag on each `div` - try:

```
gameTwoText += "<div>" + gameTwo[i] + "</div>";
```

Without the `</div>`, you never close the first `div` so each subsequent one is created as a child of the last.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, make sure you close your `DIV` tag in the loop, however you can always do this the old fashion way which will build the elements via the `DOM`:

```
var secondGame = document.getElementById('game2');
var gameTwo = ['Kansas', 'Villanova'];
var div = null;
for (var i = 0, len = gameTwo.length; i < len; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(gameTwo[i]));
    secondGame.appendChild(div);
}
```